# How to pass data parameters throw List Tile to a Stateful Widget in DART?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, widget

i need know what item in ListTile the user clicked on. And send the information on my List.

I would like to pass it with constructors.

Like this:

```
onTap: () {
            if (navigate == "Gerente") {
              push(context, LockerScreen(lockers[index]));
            } else {
              push(context, LockerUserScreen());
            }
          }
```

I receive this information on a StatefulWidget.

And this is how it looks like:

```
class LockerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return LockerScreenState();
  }
}


class LockerScreenState extends State<LockerScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { }
```

What i doesn't know how to do is send the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to pass data from one screen/widgets to another? try this:

```
class LockerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    final int lockerNumber; 
    LockerScreen(this.lockerNumber);

    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return LockerScreenState();
    }
}


class LockerScreenState extends State<LockerScreen> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        //Access it here using "widget.lockerNumber";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this can help me. I really don't know too much on how Dart works. Very much thank you!

I will test.

Comment: notify me if there any problem regarding this :)